# Get first letter of the document title

Tags: strings, xstring

I'm trying to get the first letter of the document title, but I'm not getting.
I'm using a code as:

```
\usepakage{xtring}
\StrLeft{\thetitle}{1}[\firstletter]
```

Result of compilation:

Undefined control sequence.

```
<argument> \thetitle l.439 \StrLeft{\thetitle}{1} [\firstletter] The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. \c@numresumo=\count339 \c@teorema=\count340 \c@proposicao=\count341 \c@lema=\count342 \c@corolario=\count343 \c@exemplo=\count344 \c@observacao=\count345 \c@definicao=\count346 \c@quadro=\count347 \c@loqdepth=\count348 \cftbeforequadroskip=\skip303 \cftquadroindent=\skip304 \cftquadronumwidth=\skip305 \cftbeforealgorithmtskip=\skip306 \cftalgorithmtindent=\skip307 \cftalgorithmtnumwidth=\skip308 \cftbeforelstlistingskip=\skip309 \cftlstlistingindent=\skip310 \cftlstlistingnumwidth=\skip311 \c@countcodigo=\count349 \c@count=\count350 \output@idxfile=\write10 Writing index file output.idx ) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rotating/rotating.sty Package: rotating 2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX \c@r@tfl@t=\count351 \rotFPtop=\skip312 \rotFPbot=\skip313 \rot@float@box=\box69 \rot@mess@toks=\toks65 ) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xy.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xy.tex Bootstrap'ing: catcodes, docmode, (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xyrecat.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xyidioms.tex)
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SX :) you could easily do this with plain ole' TeX: `\def\thing#1#2\bloop{first: #1; rest: #2}\def\mything#1{\thing#1\bloop}\mything{my title}` I'm going to assume you want an `xstring` solution, though :)

Comment: I want to get the document title that it is defined by tag \title. I'm using the memoir class

Comment: Well, that's not `\thetitle`, anyways – that's `\@title`. (you can see this by running `texdef -t latex title` in the command line or using `\typeout{\meaning\title}` in your document and inspecting the console output.) With my plain ole' TeX example though, you're probably going to run into expansion issues. I'd use `expl3` here.

Comment: According of Memoir documentation, I have to use `\thetitle` to get the content... But I cannot to use the `\StrLeft` to get it first letter... Though, I use `\thetitle` elsewhere in the document...

Comment: Ah, you didn't say you were using Memoir – I assumed `article` or similar.  This definitely has to do with expansion.  I'll try to fix something up.  Can you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  Just a short document that we can all work from.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, since [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) expands its arguments fully (via `\fullexpandarg`) by default. So, `\thetitle` isn't recognized, you're using it wrongly.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is occurring because `\StrLeft` is seeing `\thetitle` – not the *contents* of `\thetitle`.  `\StrLeft` doesn't really know what to do in this scenario.

You need to control when `\thetitle` is expanded:

```
\expandafter\StrLeft\expandafter{\thetitle}{1}[\firstletter]
```

Or, with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{expl3}

\title{bleh}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:NV \StrLeft \thetitle {1} [\firstletter]
\ExplSyntaxOff

\firstletter
\end{document}
```

The `expl3` syntax may appear more obtuse at first glance, but it is consistent and makes it *much* clearer about what will happen in the end.  `\exp_args:NV` will take the first two commands (called *tokens* in TeXspeak) and regurgitate them, only this time with the second command expanded into its value.  See `texdoc interface3` for further information on this and other goodies.